# Python INI File How to Separate Contents of 1 Variable into 3 Separate Variables

Tags: python, user-interface, dictionary, ini

I am working on a GUI that reads from an INI file to configure some onscreen buttons. I am stuck trying to separate some data that is returned from the INI file. Essentially I have a button "type" which is 1 of 4 options and based on the type, the GUI will assign the button a function. (I am using the INI file to make it easy to change the button abilities in the future)

What I am trying to do is sort out the buttons into groups of type and then identify which buttons are in that group into their own variable.

Here is the INI File for the button types:

```
[Button1]
type = Run Mission

[Button2]
type = Set Register

[Button3]
type = Set Register

[Button4]
type = Set Register

[Button5]
type = Indicator

[Button6]
type = Set Register

[Button7]
type = Data

[Button8]
type = Data

[Button9]
type = Data
```

And here is the code I was trying to use to pull this data. I am using configparser to read the INI file. The problem is that when I `print k` to test the data coming in, it prints `type_7, type_9, type_8` and if possible; I need these each in their own variable or separated somehow. I didn't include all the GUI code to keep the post short but if more code is needed, just let me know. I am newer to python and have seen a bunch of similar posts but can not seem to find the way to do this specifically.

```
type_dict = {}

    type_dict['type_1'] = config.get("Button1", "type")
    type_dict['type_2'] = config.get("Button2", "type")
    type_dict['type_3'] = config.get("Button3", "type")
    type_dict['type_4'] = config.get("Button4", "type")
    type_dict['type_5'] = config.get("Button5", "type")
    type_dict['type_6'] = config.get("Button6", "type")
    type_dict['type_7'] = config.get("Button7", "type")
    type_dict['type_8'] = config.get("Button8", "type")
    type_dict['type_9'] = config.get("Button9", "type")

    print type_dict

    """for k, v in type_dict.items():
        if v == "Run Mission":
            print k

    for k, v in type_dict.items():
        if v == "Set Register":
            print k

    for k, v in type_dict.items():
        if v == "Indicator":
            print k"""

    for k, v in type_dict.items():
        if v == "Data":
            print k
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Explanation for the down vote?

Comment: Well for instance the last for loop I have returns multiple keys from the dictionary since multiple keys meet the criteria for v == "Data". I was attempting to return them each in the own variable. The purpose of doing so would be so that I would have code that doesn't rely on knowing how many of each type there will be because the number of each type can be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of keys which have "Data" as their value. Does that give you what you need?

```
data_buttons = [k for k, v in type_dict.items() if v == "Data"]
```

Comment: Yes, that got them into a list which I can then parse into individual variables like I was thinking. Thank you for the suggestion!